# Form is not looping and displaying when i am trying DJANGO

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a Django view that i am trying to submit and process.

I have a ModelForm that i am trying to pass through to the HTML template. Now with the form, I want to loop through it and every time i loop through it, I want to add a prefix to the fields names so that i can process it easier.

What I have now is a view that is correctly looping though each of the items and adding the prefix, but when it is passed and displayed to the HTML template, I am only getting the result of the last template that goes through the form. I am not sure how to get that to happen and what I need to do to get it to work.

Here is the view that I have:

```
def addTransaction(request, groupId, recordId):
    user = User.objects.get(username='omar')
    group = Group.objects.get(id=groupId)
    record = Record.objects.get(id=recordId)
    transactions = Transaction.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if record.split == 1:
            form = EvenSplitTransactionForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                amount = cd['amount']
                description = cd['description']
                split_amount = SplitEven(record, amount)
                for trans in transactions:
                    if trans.record.id == record.id:
                        trans.description = description
                        trans.amount = split_amount
                        trans.save()
                return redirect('accounts')
        if record.split == 2:
            form = IndividualSplitTransactionForm(request.POST)
        return redirect('accounts')
        #--------------------------------------------------------
    else:
        if record.split == 1:
            form = EvenSplitTransactionForm()
            message = 'fill out the form below'
            parameters = {
                'record':record,
                'form':form,
                'message':message,
                'transactions':transactions,
            }
            return render(request, 'tabs/add_even_transactions.html', parameters)
        if record.split == 2:
            message = 'fill out the form below'
            for trans in transactions:
                if trans.record.id == record.id:
                    print(trans.user.username)
                    form = IndividualSplitTransactionForm(prefix=trans.user.username)
                    print(form)
            parameters = {
                'record':record,
                'form':form,
                'message':message,
                'transactions':transactions,
            }
            return render(request, 'tabs/add_individual_transaction.html', parameters)
```

Here is what is displaying as the form is going through the loop.

```
hani
<tr><th><label for="id_hani-amount">Amount:</label></th><td><input id="id_hani-amount" name="hani-amount" step="0.01" type="number" value="0.0" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_hani-description">Description:</label></th><td><input id="id_hani-description" maxlength="250" name="hani-description" type="text" /></td></tr>
rana
<tr><th><label for="id_rana-amount">Amount:</label></th><td><input id="id_rana-amount" name="rana-amount" step="0.01" type="number" value="0.0" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_rana-description">Description:</label></th><td><input id="id_rana-description" maxlength="250" name="rana-description" type="text" /></td></tr>
amer
<tr><th><label for="id_amer-amount">Amount:</label></th><td><input id="id_amer-amount" name="amer-amount" step="0.01" type="number" value="0.0" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_amer-description">Description:</label></th><td><input id="id_amer-description" maxlength="250" name="amer-description" type="text" /></td></tr>
```

and here is the html that is being displayed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="/static/css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">

  <h1>Add members to </h1>

    <p>fill out the form below</p>

  <form action="." method="POST">
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='Gnb1o5rbKqkoegYCX5biYwtZgK3XMXBa' />
    <p><label for="id_amer-amount">Amount:</label> <input id="id_amer-amount" name="amer-amount" step="0.01" type="number" value="0.0" /></p>
<p><label for="id_amer-description">Description:</label> <input id="id_amer-description" maxlength="250" name="amer-description" type="text" /></p>
    <p>Tax: <input type="text" name="tax" value=""></p>
    <p>Tip: <input type="text" name="tip" value=""></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I can get all three of the forms that are being created to pass to the html template? I want to get all of the processing and assigning done in the views.py file rather than the html file if possible.

**UPDATE**

This is the html template that i have:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Add members to {{record.name}}</h1>
  {% if message %}
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  {% endif %}
  <form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p>Tax: <input type="text" name="tax" value=""></p>
    <p>Tip: <input type="text" name="tip" value=""></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is the second snippet a template code? I can't see where is the parameter using.

Comment: that is what is  displaying in the command line when i print the forms through every cycle...

Comment: could you post your template codes?

Comment: the html template code will be added to the original post as updated,...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/) feature in django.
For using forms in template, add codes in a view file like:

```
...
from django.forms import formset_factory
...
ISTFormSet=formset_factory(IndividualSplitTransactionForm,extra=3)
```

and pass the `ISTFormset` to template as parameter.
In template file you can use it like:

```
...
<form action="." method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for form in ISTFormset %}
{{ form.as_p }}
{% endfor %}
<p>Tax: <input type="text" name="tax" value=""></p>
<p>Tip: <input type="text" name="tip" value=""></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
...
```

I don't know what your form's actual parameters are. so you may edit the codes but the idea is same. 
you can receive the post data with `for` statement in a view file.
please refer to the link above to find more. there are plenty of features.